# Brand new SSD not working!

Tags: ssd

I replaced the built-in hard drive with a Samsung 870 Evo 500 GB SSD on my Mid 2010 MacBook Pro 13 inch (A1278), and attempted to reinstall Mac OS X Lion 10.7.1 from a bootable USB. When I try to erase or partition the SSD, it says: Unable to write to the last block of the device. When I attempt to reinstall Mac OS as is, the SSD does not show up.

Comment: had you formatted your drive to MacOS Extended (Journaled) format? I think it should help.

Comment: did you reset the SMC

Comment: Does that machine only run Lion?  You may need a firmware update to talk to that drive.

Comment: "Unable to write to the last block of the device" is often a cabling issue. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=Unable+to+write+to+the+last+block+of+the+device